# Annotate a Django query for all users in admin panel

Tags: django

I have a query like this:

```
user.ihaveinvited.all().filter(current_status='passive').values('id').distinct()
```

to get all the distinct users with a certain status.  I want to apply this to something like:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(uniq_passive_invites=ALLUSERS.ihaveinvited.all().filter(current_status='passive').values('id').distinct()
```

so the question is running this query for all users as a queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at another [question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517751/django-annotations-with-filter) and they seemed closely related. Adding a count with a filter requires a bit more work, but it can be achieved.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(ihaveinvited__invitee__current_status='passive', then=1),
            default=0,
            output_field=models.IntegerField()
        )
    ))
    return qs
```

Comment: Please consider leaving a comment as to whether this answer works for you, and if not, add the errors to your comment (or edit the question).

Comment: sorry I was away, I really appreciate all your help.  I didn't realize the strength of the Django admin panel and your answers have helped to unlock some new ideas.  I will be sure to give you a check as soon as I get to work tomorrow and confirm your response.

Comment: I get the error `Relation fields do not support nested lookups`

Comment: Would you be able to add your User and Invitation models to the question?

Comment: a concept that would kind of help, is I want to get `username` and `current_status` so I can get all the unique instances of these things.  So if you invite a passive user twice, I only want it to count once.

Comment: The error `Relation fields do not support nested lookups` comes from using the wrong field names. Try replacing `ihaveinvited__invitee__current_status` with the related_name and field names defined in your models. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696122/django-spanning-relationships) may help also.

Comment: yes that error was from a misspelling but the real concern is that it only provides a count, not a count that includes the user's name and the current status and then gets individual occurrences of the tuple.   Like I want (('rob', 'passive'), ('rob', 'passive')) to count as 1.